# Show spinner in LXDE

Tags: debian, lxde

Recently I've installed Debian with LXDE on a very old computer (from my grandma). It takes ~ 5-15 seconds to start Firefox, but when I double-click a program, there's no loading indicator, which is very annoying. How can I let it show a spinner while it's loading the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

Turns out it is a **[bug in Openbox version 3.6.1-2 in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=838326)**. An upgrade to Openbox version `3.6.1-3` should resolve this issue.

---

What you need is a *cursor theme*. I myself used to have **[this](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Pulse+Glass?content=124442)** on one of my Arch Linux machines with Xfce (now sadly buried due to old age).

There is a good (and short!) guide **[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/1mihq5/how_to_change_mouse_cursors/)** on how to install and activate the new cursor theme using `lxappearance`, if you don't already have it installed, it is **[available for Debian Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lxappearance)**.

In short:

- Download the cursor theme.
- Open `lxappearance` (customize look and feel under preferences).
- Click install on the mouse prefs page and open the `tar.gz` you have downloaded.

The theme I linked to above, and used previously, shows a spinning circle when a program starts up. I am sure there are plenty of other themes with different looks.

Comment: Atm I'm just using the default Adwaita cursor theme, but doesn't it already include a spinning cursor?

Comment: I honestly have no idea! Never used that myself.

Comment: A-ha! Seems lik it is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=838326). But according to the bug report it should be fixed in Openbox version `3.6.1-3`.

Comment: You're right! It was indeed a bug, after updating to Openbox `3.6.1-3` it works fine, so can you edit your answer so it say that? If so, I'll accept your answer…

Comment: Yay! Glad you were able to solve this! I made an edit to my post as requested. Best regards!